# NSTableView loads data, but cannot reload

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, reloaddata

I've got two NSTableViews set up, being populated by one nstableviewdatasource and delegate. Both tableviews receive data when first loaded without issue, however they refuse to reload data. Both tableview datasource and delegates are connected to my tableviewcontroller class object in the xib.

I've confirmed that my method, which sets new data to the array I use to populate the tableviews, actually receives the changed data. This method is the only way I populate the array that the datasource delegate methods use. It is being reloaded from the main thread:

```
myArray = [classThatHoldsNewVariables.array mutableCopy]; 
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

-numberOfRowsInTableView does not get called with reloadData. It only gets called on app launch.

I've tried manually setting the datasource and delegate methods in code, without any success. I've tried so many different ways of getting reloadData to work, and nothing happens.

Help  :(

**EDIT:**

I fixed the problem. It was an instance issue, where I was alloc init-ing my nstableviewdatasource from another class to reload the data. Init does not load the instance used by the nib, so it's reloading another instance of my tableview, which isn't shown to the user. I solved this by implementing nsnotifications in my tableviewcontroller class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was an instance issue, where I was alloc init-ing my nstableviewdatasource from another class to reload the data. Init does not load the instance used by the nib, so it's reloading another instance of my tableview, which isn't shown to the user. I solved this by implementing nsnotifications in my tableviewcontroller class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `myTableView` is `nil`, thus sending it the `reloadData` method isn't doing anything.

If it's an outlet, make sure it's connected in the xib. If not, note that a `UITableViewController`'s table view is, by default, referenced by the `tableView` property, not `myTableView`.

Comment: It's definitely connected, as I can gather the identifier via myTableView. This is an OS X table view, not a UITableView.